# Desplazamiento de Imágenes con Bootstrap 4

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4, flexbox, md-bootstrap

Requiero saber que codificación debo aplicar para que independientemente del orden del div de texto e imagen, siempre la imagen se desplace hacia abajo en modo tablet o md.

Ejemplo:

ENTRADA 1

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                    TEXTO
                </div>

                <div>
                    IMAGEN
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

ENTRADA 2

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    IMAGEN
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                    TEXTO
                </div>                
            </div>
</div>
```

En la primera entrada coloco el div de texto y después el div de imagen.
En la segunda entrada coloco el div de imagen y después el div de texto.

Deseo que cuando este en pantalla modo tablet o md, las imágenes se desplacen hacia abajo, porque actualmente, en la segunda entrada me pone la imagen hacia arriba en vez de hacia abajo.

Gracias Anticipada.

Comment: ¿Deseas que sea únicamente en resolución md? Porque podrías hacerlo global, que independiente del tamaño y del código, la imagen quede en la parte inferior.

Comment: Saludos, es solo para cuando este en pantalla mobil y tablet, es decir, sm y md boostrap 4. Ojala puedas ayudarme, gracias.-

Answer (score 1):

Una buena solución para tu problema es trabajar con 'flexbox'. Te permitirá color los elementos como necesitas y moverlos de una maner sencilla. A continuación de dejo un ejemplo de como puedes hacer para la necesidad concreta que planteas:

```css
      .row {margin-bottom: 50px;}
      .conFlex{display:flex; flex-direction: column;}

      .texto {padding:50px 100px; background-color: aqua; color: yellowgreen; font-size: 1em;font-weight: bold;}
      .imagen {padding:50px 100px; background-color: rebeccapurple; color: whitesmoke; font-size: 1em;font-weight: bold;}

      /*@media only screen and (max-width:768px)*/@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
        .container .conFlex {display:flex; flex-direction: row-reverse; flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;}
      }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<div class="container">

    <div class="row conFlex">
        <div class="col-12 imagen">
                            IMAGEN
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 texto">
                        TEXTO
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 texto">
                TEXTO
         </div>
         <div class="col-12 imagen">
                    IMAGEN
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

En este ejemplo he dejado comentado el 'breakpoint' de tablet y puesto uno de menores dimensiones para que si quieres probar aquí reduzcas el ancho de la pantalla con el inspector o manualmente para que veas como funciona el código y cambia los elementos de posición.

Además te copio aquí un enlace que te puede resultar de ayuda a la hora de aplicar 'flexbox': [css triks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)